# Connect to Live HTML Preview from another device on same network

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have downloaded and installed an extension to preview a webpage I'm working on inside the editor.  It works fine, but I would like to also test the same HTML code on my mobile device as well. I have a normal home WiFi network.  I was wondering if it is possible to somehow hook into the preview from another device besides the host computer. Is there a way to view the website from my phone on the same WiFi network, and access all of the website's served files, like index.html, /styles/*.css, /scripts/*.js, /images/*.jpg, etc? 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple solution

1. turn on the live server on your pc
2. check the port where it's running
   will look like 4400
3. check your LAN IP address will look like 192.172.123
4. Enter the address with the port number in this form (192.172.123:4400) on another device connected to the same router or device

Boom you can view changes as same you are using the same device

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't realize that this functionality is already included in the wonderful extension that I originally downloaded - it's called Live Server by Ritwick Dey.  On his GitHub repo, he outlines steps to remotely connect to the served website via another device on the same network (your phone for example).  Tried it and it worked the first time!

https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/faqs.md

Comment: Thanks. With my ethernet conected PC it didn't work for me using Localhost/127.0.0.1:xxxx. I had to use the local ip my router was giving my PC: 198.162....